# AWS Event bridge does not notify status of AWS App Runner

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge, amazon-app-runner

I'm trying to setup a AWS event bridge rule that sends a message to an SNS topic in case of a deployment failure.

However, AWS event bridge does not seem to catch any events.
This is the cloudformation template I use to setup the rules and SNS topic:
It is based on the documentation given [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apprunner/latest/dg/monitor-ev.html)

```
  LabAPIEventRule:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      Description: "notification on application failure"
      EventPattern:
        Fn::ToJsonString:
          detail-type: [ "AppRunner Service Operation Status Change" ]
          source: [ "aws.apprunner" ]
          account: [ !Ref AWS::AccountId ]
          detail:
            Status:
            - "CreateServiceFailed"
            - "DeleteServiceFailed"
            - "UpdateServiceFailed"
            - "DeploymentFailed"
            - "PauseServiceFailed"
            - "ResumeServiceFailed"
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: "event-${EnvironmentCode}-${ProductName}-apprunner-failure"
      RoleArn: !GetAtt LabFailureSenderIAMRole.Arn
      Targets:
        - Arn: !Ref LabAPISNSTarget
          Id: "1"

  LabFailureSenderIAMRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      RoleName:
        Fn::Sub: "iam-${AWS::Region}-${EnvironmentCode}-${ProductName}-lab-failure-role"
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - events.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: 'sns'
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: "*"
                Resource: !Ref LabAPISNSTarget

  LabAPISNSTarget:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties:
      DisplayName:
        Fn::Sub: "sns-${EnvironmentCode}-${ProductName}-apprunner-failure-sender"
      Subscription:
        - Endpoint: "my email"
          Protocol: email
```

I expected to receive a notification of a deployment failure in my inbox.

I created a new app runner instance with faulty code that does not run, but received no notification.
I created an app runner instance that succesfully deployed, then updated to fail a deployment, but once again no notification.
I tested my SNS topic by sending a message to it, and that works fine.
Do you guys have any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Ensure that EventBridge also has permission to PutEvents to the rule.